# Can't get date to sort properly with for XML Path

Tags: sql-server, sorting, date

I am trying to get the results of my for xml path to sort correctly by the date field.  I know it is because I have converted the date to a varchar, but I can't figure out how to covert it back to a date in the for XML path statement so it will sort correctly.  I have tried several different scenarios and can't get it to work.

Here is my code

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @cols = STUFF(
  (SELECT DISTINCT
    ','+QUOTENAME(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cs.DATE_CREATED, 103), 7)) as [date1]
     FROM claim_status cs 
     WHERE cs.DATE_CREATED >= DATEADD(mm, -12, getdate()) 
     ORDER BY [date1] FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');
select @cols
```

The results look like this

```
case_id 01/2018 02/2018 03/2018 04/2017 04/2018 05/2017 06/2017 07/2017 08/2017 09/2017 10/2017 11/2017 12/2017
```

You can see that the dates are not sorted correctly.  I have tried doing a cast in the order by to convert it back to a date first, but for some reason then it doesn't recognize the date1 field.  So when I change it to this, I get Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
Invalid column name 'date1'.

```
SET @cols = STUFF(
(SELECT DISTINCT
   ','+QUOTENAME(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cs.DATE_CREATED, 103), 7)) as date1
   FROM claim_status cs 
   WHERE cs.DATE_CREATED >= DATEADD(mm, -12, getdate()) 
   ORDER BY cast(date1 as date) FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to order by `cs.DATE_CREATED`.

It would be nice to simply replace `date1` with `cs.DATE_CREATED` in the `ORDER BY` clause.  However when using the `DISTINCT` clause, SQL Server requires that any columns used in the `ORDER BY` clause must also appear in the result set.

Adding `cs.DATE_CREATED` to the result set would complicate the generated XML, and probably require a more complicated XQuery expression in the `value` function.

A simpler solution is to use a common table expression (CTE) to build a distinct result set that can then be concatenated.

```
;WITH cte
AS
(
  SELECT
    DISTINCT
      cs.DATE_CREATED
    FROM
      claim_status AS cs
    WHERE
      cs.DATE_CREATED >= DATEADD(mm, -12, getdate())
)
SELECT @cols = STUFF(
  (SELECT
    ','+QUOTENAME(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cte.DATE_CREATED, 103), 7))
     FROM cte
     ORDER BY cte.DATE_CREATED FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');

select @cols
```